# Artwork for crossplatform mobile application made in adobe air

Tags: android, apache-flex, ipad, mobile, air

What is the best way to create artwork for cross platform mobile application that is made using Adobe air. This application runs on iphone,iphone4,ipad,ipod,android,blackberry,desktop.

How should we approach to this issue. Any suggestions!

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of this question.  Anything you couldn't find already online?  Any bitmap or flash supported vector (swf, fxg, some svg) would work fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the approach is the use FXG elements and re-create them for each of the three main DPI.  I believe they are 160 (most tablets), 240 (most phones), and 320 (iPhone 4).

You're code can check the applicationDPI and decide which assets to use.

You can create FXG graphics in many of the Adobe programs, including Fireworks, Photoshop, Illustrator, and Flash Catalyst.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have one confusion regarding tablet ones, they have larger screen sizes comparative to mobile devices. On one hand I create image for lets say 320x480 in all three dpi, should it be working fine for iPad and motorolla xoom?

Comment: @imran In mobile development, you'll need to use different pixel height and width at each DPI resolution to get your asset to take up the same "space" on each screen.  For example, If you have 10 pixels per inch, then you'll need a 10 pixels image to get an inch long image.  IF you have 20 pixels per inch, that same 10 pixel image will only take up a half inch of screen real estate.  There is a good table on such things at this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html (Table 3)

Comment: This link helped me a lot but my confusion is still there. I am making an application using Adobe Air that will be running on iPhone, BB and Android. In iphone you would have three types (iPod, iphone and iPhone-retina, ipad) and multiple types in android as well. So you would have so many different dpis and screen sizes. This link addresses this problem with android only. Should I adopt the same approach for adobe air as well? or should I go for individual art assets for iphones, ipads and androids?

Comment: @imran The Flex Framework lumps 'everything' into three DPIs using the applicationDPI property.  More info on that here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html